# Combining Matrix System of equations

Tags: matrices

This is a question I came across while reviewing: I'm looking for some guidance on how to approach it
I have the system of matrix equations below:

C*z + transpose(A)y = f

A*z = g

1. Express this problem as a matrix equation Mx = b for suitably defined matrix M and vectors x and b.
2. Assuming the coefficient matrix M is nonsingular, what are the high order costs, as a function of n, of solving this system using Gaussian elimination?
3. If A is nonsingular, show that the high order costs can be reduced.

So far I have for 1 that M = [C transpose(A); A 0], x = [z;y] and b = (f;g), but I'm not sure how to approach the rest of the questions